# Why does R 2.14.1 output certain special characters incorrectly in xls?

Tags: r, xls

Using R 2.14.1, I sometimes output xls files. However, recently, I've noticed that `-` in the data object to output are converted into some code similar to `+AC0` in the actual xls file. This persists when reading back into R. Similarly, underscores are converted to `.A+.` or something similar.

Example code:
`write.table(obj1, file="ex1.xls", sep="\t", row.names=F, na="")`

I can't remember this happening in previous versions of R.

Any ideas on solutions?

Comment: what exactly do you do? can you provide the coding that produces the described behaviour?

Comment: Does this also happen with the latest relaes of R (2.15.2)? Whcih package do you use to write .xls files?

Comment: My money is on locale-dependent UTF translation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How can I address this problem? I'll try 2.15.2 as soon as I can.

Comment: @thijsvandenbergh Updated with example

Comment: Two things: 1. a `".xls"` does not make an Excel file. If you use `sep="\t"` you're making a tab separated file. It would be more appropriate to give it a `".txt"` extension. (You can still open it with Excel.)

Comment: 2. I just tried it (2.15.2) using, since you didn't provide an object, `obj1 = data.frame(a = "dash - dash", b = 2)`, and had no trouble recovering the `-` either opening in Excel or re-reading into R. But @CarlWitthoft is probably right and it's not really an R problem.

Comment: @shujaa Thanks; so it's a problem with OS UTF translation? I've been coding on Unix and Mac machines.

Comment: @Kaleb That's my guess. Does my example work for you? It works for me.

Comment: Yes thanks. I've moved over to using txt for everything now.